# Is it okay for Christians to drink wine while being Christians?

Tags: christianity

A long ago I read that according to Islam it's possible for Christian to be Christian and eat pig and drink wine while being in a status of d'ima (or something like that). Is that true, or it's forbidden also for non-Muslims according to Islam?

N.b. This question may be practical in some Muslim countries. According to Islam, do they need to let Christians drink wine and eat pig or it's forbidden also for them if we are talking about sharia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Christians and Jews are permitted to drink wine, provided that they do it privately, out of the view of Muslims living in Muslim cities.

That is because the prohibition on wine is unique to Islam and is not present in their religion, rather their religion even requires them to drink wine in some of their customs. Under shariah we can not meddle with their religion because our contract with them is on the condition of paying Jizyah and not on the condition of them abandoning their religion.

> #### لا إكراه في الدين
>
> There shall be no compulsion in [acceptance of] the religion.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 2:256](http://quran.com/2/256)</sup>

**References:**

<sup>**Note:** The English translation is my own, so treat with caution as may contain paraphrasing etc.</sup>

> عدم التعرض لكنائسهم ولا لخمورهم وخنازيرهم ما لم يظهروها، فإن أظهروا الخمر أرقناها عليهم
>
> Interference shall not be done with their places of worship; nor with their wine and their pigs as long as they do not  use them openly, and if they openly display wine it will be spilled
>
> <sup>— [Islamic Jurisprudence and its Proofs (الفقه الإسلامي وأدلته)](https://shamela.ws/book/384/5704#p1)</sup>
>
> أقروا المعاملة بالخمر والخنزير بين أهل الذمة، بنحو شرب أو بيع أو هبة أو مثلها، بشرط عدم الإظهار؛ لأن مقتضى عقد الذمة: أن يقر الذمي على الكفر مقابل الجزية، ويترك هو وشأنه فيما يعتقده من الحل والحرمة، والمعاملة بالخمر والخنزير مما يعتقد جوازها
>
> Dealings in wine and pigs by the *ahl al-Dhimmah* are to be tolerated, such as their drinking or sale or gift or the like, on the condition that they do not do it openly.
> That is because the contract of Dhimma requires that a Dhimmi be allowed to remain on Kufr by payment of Jizyah, and that he be left alone regarding his belief on halal and haram, and his belief is that dealings in wine and pigs is halal.
>
> <sup>— [Encyclopedia of Islamic Jurisprudence (الموسوعة الفقهية)](https://shamela.ws/book/11430/4198#p1)</sup>